# Not able to build coredns project because of failure to fetch a dependency

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get

I tried to build coredns https://github.com/coredns/coredns/  by cloning the repo in my gopath and running make, which produced the following error

```
GO111MODULE=on go generate coredns.go
GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0  go build -v -ldflags="-s -w -X github.com/coredns/coredns/coremain.GitCommit=f6eb2a4" -o coredns
../../../../pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.19.0/internal/channelz/types_linux.go:26:2: 
../../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a/unix/affinity_linux.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'coredns' failed
make: *** [coredns] Error 1
```

I ran `go mod tidy` and it fixed the error due `x/sys` but after that another error appeared

```
# github.com/miekg/dns
Dev/Projects/golang/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/miekg/dns@v1.1.6/scan.go:436:29: string not terminated
Dev/Projects/golang/gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/miekg/dns@v1.1.6/scan.go:436:44: syntax error: unexpected EOF, expecting comma or )
```

when I tried go get for this package I got the same error, I dont have this package in my gopath neither do I have it in my cache directory.

whats seems to be the problem here?

Comment: What version of go you use?

Comment: I was using 1.11.5 when this occured, then I thought of upgrading go but I still got the same error, currently I am on 1.12

Comment: Do `git reset --hard` and run `make` again with 1.12 version of go.

Comment: that just brought back the `x/sys` error again

Comment: GO111MODULE=on CGO_ENABLED=0  go build -v -ldflags="-s -w -X github.com/coredns/coredns/coremain.GitCommit=f6eb2a4" -o coredns
../../../../pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.19.0/internal/channelz/types_linux.go:26:2: 
../../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a/unix/affinity_linux.go:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'coredns' failed
make: *** [coredns] Error 1                                                                                                            
@VadimAshikhman

Comment: Check `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20190215142949-d0b11bdaac8a/unix/affinity_linux.go` file, is it empty? If so try to remove everything in `$GOPATH/pkg` dir and run again, or reinstall go.